# basename not giving me complete URL PHP

Tags: php

Right now I'm printing the current URL I have and it kinda does it ok:

```
$currentURL = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

The problem is that it only prints

```
solutions.php
```

instead of printing

```
solutions.php?id=581298a7-6c08-11e3-9bea-742f689f29f1
```

Anybody knows why this is happening? I need to get to print the part of

```
?id=581298a7-6c08-11e3-9bea-742f689f29f1
```

Because then I will be performing a substring to get just the ID.

Comment: That's by design, `basename()` is for file paths. You want to use http://php.net/parse_url instead

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which parses a URL and returns its various components in a usable array. You'll also want to make sure you're parsing the correct string; in this case use:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Full usage:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Comment: It also worth mentioning about where to take the whole requested url (since OP tries to extract it from the wrong place)

Comment: Btw, `$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` is far from a complete url. It doesn't take into account different port and http schema. PS: but still it would be enough for OP, +1

Comment: @zerkms for sure, but OP can read the docs and expand that if necessary via `SERVER_PROTOCOL`, `SERVER_PORT`, etc. And of course it won't work for HTTPS either. Need a sophisticated function for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, because everything from the `?` afterwards are not part of the filename. The parameters that you're looking for are in the `$_GET` superglobal.